# OpenCV Identify rows in Table of variable size

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a bunch of scans of forms that all look like this:

[image]

I'm trying to take out each row to make each on its own image (a row being the box with 10 all the way to the right of the form). I've written a function (in python) that will find all the boxes, OCR each box on its own (using tesseract), determine whether the ID label is present (in this blank form, just the 10), and use the height of the box and width of the whole table to pull out the row.

The problem with this process is the OCR; some of the tables are so pixelated that no text is detected at all, so that row doesn't get taken out of the table. I used the row rectangle boundaries of one form that had a good OCR result to take out the rows from all the forms, but, for some reason, some of the forms have differently sized headers, or the row height is larger or smaller than 'normal' (I've resized every table to be the same resolution). One thing that does not change is the general layout of the text windows within each row, though one form's rows might be taller or shorter relative to another table.

My question: how can I identify each row as a feature using one (or a set of) example(s), while accounting for the slight variation in the row position in various examples? I would appreciate any ideas you might have.

I'm working with Python 2.7, OpenCV 3.1.0 (on windows), and the same with scikit-image and scikit-learn on an ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 2):

`HoughLines` helps you find the lines in the image. After that you need to filter out all the non-horizontal ones. You can use the remaining ones to find out where you need to split the image.